# Deprecated: mysql_connect():

Tags: mysql, deprecation

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/gorilla911/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1520
>
> Notice: Undefined index: acb5ec in
>   /home/gorilla911/public_html/wp-content/plugins/user-role-editor/includes/class-ure-screen-help.php
>   on line 1

I checked my PHP version and it's 5.6.31. Also, I can not access `wp-admin`.

Comment: any one help me

Comment: Try to ask a different question. This question is answered, and you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL extension:

- Is not under active development
- Is **officially [deprecated][1]** as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013).
- Has been **[removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql) entirely** as of PHP 7.0 (released December 2015)
- Lacks an OO interface
- Doesn't support:

  - Non-blocking, asynchronous queries
  - **[Prepared statements][2] or parameterized queries**
  - Stored procedures
  - Multiple Statements
  - Transactions
  - The "new" password authentication method (on by default in MySQL 5.6; required in 5.7)
  - All of the functionality in MySQL 5.1

Since it is deprecated, using it makes your code less future proof.

Comment: I try to reset password but same problem please help me